# FFmpeg libx264 Llicense

Tags: java, ffmpeg, libx264

We have Java Spring application. The application interacts with FFmpeg through Java Runtime.exec() call in order to encode video into mp4 format. Are we ok with the commercial aspect of our application, having in mind that libx264 is released under GPL license, ffmpeg under LGPL license and we are using ffmpeg as external command line utility already installed and hosted on the client's computer?

Comment: http://x264licensing.com/

Comment: You should probably ask a lawyer rather than programmers.  This question is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:** Is it perfectly alright to incorporate the whole FFmpeg core into my own commercial product?

And

> **Answer:** You might have a problem here. There have been cases where companies have used FFmpeg in their products. These companies found out that once you start trying to make money from patented technologies, the owners of the patents will come after their licensing fees. Notably, MPEG LA is vigilant and diligent about collecting for MPEG-related technologies

[Source on the bottom of this page.](https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html)